# Irrationality of angles for sequences of character sums or Kloosterman sums

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $\mathbb{E}$ is an ordinary smooth projective curve of genus $g \geqslant 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then all its normalized Frobenius angles $\alpha_j, j=1,2, \ldots, 2 g$, are irrational.
So I wondering if there existed an irrationality of angles for sequences of character sums which denoted by
$$
\mathcal{S}_R(n)=\frac{1}{q^{n / 2}} \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_{q^*}^*} \psi\left(\operatorname{Tr}_{q^n} / \mathbb{F}_q(R(x))\right).
$$
Or under some conditions. Or even for Kloosterman sums.